# How to write an infix function

Tags: f#

Is there a way to write an infix function not using symbols? Something like this:

```
let mod x y = x % y
x mod y
```

Maybe a keyword before "mod" or something.

Comment: You might be interested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2210854/can-you-define-your-own-operators-in-f

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The existing answer is correct - you cannot define an infix function in F# (just a custom infix operator). Aside from the trick with pipe operators, you can also use extension members:

```
// Define an extension member 'modulo' that 
// can be called on any Int32 value
type System.Int32 with
  member x.modulo n = x % n

// To use it, you can write something like this:
10 .modulo 3
```

Note that the space before `.` is needed, because otherwise the compiler tries to interpret `10.m` as a numeric literal (like `10.0f`).

I find this a bit more elegant than using pipeline trick, because F# supports both functional style and object-oriented style and extension methods are - in some sense - close equivalent to implicit operators from functional style. The pipeline trick looks like a slight misuse of the operators (and it may look confusing at first - perhaps more confusing than a method invocation).

That said, I have seen people using other operators instead of pipeline - perhaps the most interesting version is this one (which also uses the fact that you can omit spaces around operators):

```
// Define custom operators to make the syntax prettier
let (</) a b = a |> b
let (/>) a b = a <| b    
let modulo a b = a % b 

// Then you can turn any function into infix using:
10 </modulo/> 3
```

But even this is not really an established idiom in the F# world, so I would probably still prefer extension members.

Comment: It has been a while since I've written/coded anything, but this looks like it achieves the same thing as extension methods in C#. Sweet!

Comment: @Iter This **is** an extension method :)

Comment: Sorry for commenting on this old post, but your operator pair is wrong: because of operator precedence, `10 </modulo/> 3` is equivalent to `modulo 3 10`, not `modulo 10 3`. One solution is to define `let (/>) f x y = f y x` instead. Or you can use another pair of operators with the right precedence, such as `<.` and `.>`.

Comment: kind of cool idea but doesn't really improve on 10 |> modulo <| 3

Answer (score 13):

Not that I know of, but you can use the left and right pipe operators. For example

```
let modulo x y = x % y

let FourMod3 =  4 |> modulo <| 3
```

Comment: Above is considered 'pseudo infix'

nothing wrong with it, just pointing that out, I actually like this notation at times

Answer (score 1):

To add a little bit to the answers above, you can create a custom infix operators but the vocabulary is limited to:

```
 !, $, %, &, *, +, -, ., /, <, =, >, ?, @, ^, |, and ~
```

Meaning you can build your infix operator using combining these symbols.

Please check the full documentation on MS Docs.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/operator-overloading

Comment: This gave me the impression that the operators are limited to the list here, while actually in the link it says combinations of such characters can be used to form operator symbols.