# What F# sorcery is this (>=>)?

Tags: f#

The below code snippet came from [here](http://bartoszsypytkowski.com/hipsterize-your-backend-for-the-greater-good-with-akka-net-f-and-some-ddd-flavor/) and from the context I understand what it is doing via pattern matching, but how it is doing it and that operator(s) has me for a loop. MSDN was not helpful. If that is an operator, does it have a name? Sorry if there is some missing google fu on my part.

```
let (>=>) f1 f2 arg =
  match f1 arg with
  | Ok data -> f2 data
  | Error e -> Error e
```

**UPDATE:**
Indeed it might be the case that the operator is overloaded, and thanks for the link to the other SO question, I guess the core of my question was what is that overloaded operator's semantics. Looking at the other links (>>=) seems to be the typical bind operator.

Comment: You should probably read [this](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/recipe-part2/) article on Railway Oriented Programming, it will explain it better than I can in an answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you define your own operators in F#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2210854/can-you-define-your-own-operators-in-f)

Comment: https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%3E%3D%3E

Comment: The Suave webserver is using that extensively and it helped me to understand it, have a look at the examples.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

That's the *Kleisli composition* operator for monads. It allows you to compose functions with signatures like `'a -> M<'b>` and `'b -> M<'c'>` where `M` is monadic: in your case the `Result<'t>` from the linked article.

`>=>` is really just a function composition, but `>>` wouldn't work here since the return type of the first function isn't the argument of the second one - it is wrapped in a `Result<'t>` and needs to be unwrapped, which is exactly what `>=>` implementation does.

---

It could be defined in terms of `>>=` as well:

```
let (>=>) f1 f2 arg =
    f1 arg >>= f2
```

It seems that Haskell's Control.Monad package uses this definition. The full type signature might also be helpful (taken from [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/src/Control-Monad.html#%3E%3D%3E)):

```
-- | Left-to-right Kleisli composition of monads.
(>=>)       :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> (b -> m c) -> (a -> m c)
f >=> g     = \x -> f x >>= g
```

Yet another fun fact is that Kleisli composition makes the three [monad laws](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monad_laws) easier to express by only using functions (and in my opinion it makes them much clearer):

- Left identity: `return >=> g ≡ g`
- Right identity: `f >=> return ≡ f`
- Associativity: `(f >=> g) >=> h ≡ f >=> (g >=> h)`

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I am going to take a minute and try and digest this. I just wanted to confirm that the triple bar is not equality or assignment, but definition? Also, how do you write that symbol in SO?

Comment: The triple bar `≡` is extensional equality in this case. For *pure* functions it means that if you provide the same input to both left and right sides, you will get the same output from both.

Comment: Thank you, this finally made sense, when I saw how it relates to the bind operation.

Comment: "Functions of shapes" wtf

Comment: @Konrad I would say "signatures", but those aren't really valid F# signatures... Any idea how I could improve the phrasing there?

Comment: Signatures make more sense here