# What is programming language support define your own custom operator?

Tags: python, c++, math, operator-overloading, operators

I know that many language, C++, Python etc, support operator overloading, and we can redefine standart operators like +. But if we need add new operator?

Comment: What "operator" would you like to add?

Comment: In many languages that simply isn't possible without an outside library (I know this to be true for C++). I wonder, then, if a new operator should instead just be a function.

You may find more on this here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8425077/can-i-create-a-new-operator-in-c-and-how

Comment: Why you downvote question without any comment?

Comment: So we can make the `<3` operator? :)

Comment: What is your question? How to define a new operator in `c++`? In `python`? Why is this question tagged `math`?

Comment: If you're bored you can write an operator based programming language,.. if you do I'd be glad to help ;)

Comment: Different languages support operator overloading in different ways.   Depending on the language, and what operator you need to "add", the spectrum runs from "impossible" to "possible".

Comment: A major problem would be to define the precedence of your new operator relatively to the standard ones, and the rules for associativity. Unless the language explicitely gives you control over this, you're out of luck.

Comment: This question is a moving target without an objective. Maybe you are really looking for [Functional Programing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming)? Please update your question.

Comment: I guess you want to run some experiments and that's why you don't have a precise description. If so, try Smalltalk; it will not limit your thinking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither C++ nor Python ([C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8425077/can-i-create-a-new-operator-in-c-and-how), [Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932328/python-defining-my-own-operators)) support the overloading of "new" operators (although C++ does support overloading the `new` operator). Overloading operators is just syntactic sugar though - you can always just define a member function, name it something that explains its behaviour better than a single character operator could, and call it instead.

There do exist languages where this is possible: for example Haskell, a beautiful language that does allow you to define your own operators, by using symbols for the name and surrounding them with parentheses, eg:

```
(!!!) :: [a] -> Integer -> a
(x:xl) !!! 0 = x
(_:xl) !!! n = xl !!! (n-1)
    _  !!! _ = error "Index out of bounds"
```

(note this is just a redefinition of the standard `!!` function, I'm unimaginative...)

Comment: Does this work with unicode symbols?
I really want to write something like this: foo = a ⛷ b

Comment: @Maaaaa Depends on if the interpreter supports Unicode - an online one I just found [here](http://rextester.com/l/haskell_online_compiler) doesn't, but GHCi might (can't test at the moment).

Comment: FYI Scala supports custon operators too

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there is any language with the feature.
But you can always create your own interpreter or something similar in order to process your custom code and transform it into code of the desired language.
As the simplest variant, you can write a tool(or even extension for IDE), which will find something like

```
return_type operator$(typename arg1, typename arg2);
```

and insert something like

```
return_type reloaded_operator_dollar(typename arg1, typename arg2);
```

in its place.
The same goes for transforming

```
auto result = arg1 $ arg2;
```

into

```
auto result = reloaded_operator_dollar(arg1, arg2);
```

---

upd: It seems, there are such feature in FORTH and Haskell. Thanks to Neil Butterworth for the information.

Comment: "I don't think there is any language with the feature" - FORTH, Haskell?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2210854/can-you-define-your-own-operators-in-f Seems F# too. But both is functional.

Comment: @DmitrySokolov it seems more like simple overloading. Because only symbols `!%&*+-./<=>@^|~` can start an operator. In other words, it won't be quite "new".